# JavaFX TextArea onSelectionChange method

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, listener

Can I somehow implement a `onSelectionChange` method for my JavaFX Textarea?
I want some code to fire on the selection change event but looks like, it doesn't have such a method. Is it possible to implement it with listeners?

Comment: how about reading the api doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a listener to the text area's [selected text](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectedTextProperty):

```
textArea.selectedTextProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    // ...
});
```